# toastr style doesn't work well with Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, toastr

I'm using toastr in my laravel project so when I include all CSS and js files and I write the link:
JS:

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/toastr.min.js') }}"></script>
```

css:

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/toastr.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

toastr command:

```
    <script>
    Command: toastr["success"]("My name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father. Prepare to die!")

toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": false,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "5000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
}
</script>
```

the style of the alert appear in white background and white texts , like without style at all.

I tried to put the direct cdn but I got the same problem

[image]